# Windows 10 вылетает с синим экраном

Tags: windows, bsod

Постоянно вылетает синий экран с надписью thread stuck in device driver.

До этого была установлена Ubuntu. После ее удаления, из под UEFI все равно пытался загружаться GRUB, проходя мимо загрузочную флешку. После танцев с бубнами удалось удалить GRUB и установить Windows. Но установка не завершалась до конца(бесконечно висела надпись "пожалуйста подождите").

Тогда я воткнул жесткий диск в другой компьютер и доустановил Windows. После этого и отключения secure boot все-таки удалось завести Windows в режиме Legacy(под UEFI иногда запускается, а иногда нет (даже не доходит до загрузки Windows)).

Когда Windows запускается, он принимает диск за LiveUSB (понял это, так как вылазит окно, в котором написано "Windows To Go, не вытаскивайте носитель ..."
Так же иногда при включении всплывает ошибка "параметры вашего оборудования изменились, пожалуйста перезагрузите компьютер", даже если ничего не устанавливалось.

P.S проблема еще не решена

Comment: Windows это не Linux. Тут нельзя взять и просто починить. Правильное решение будет снести все и поставить винду по новому. Я в свое время переносил с обычного диска на ssd линукс+винду (дуалбут). Генту после почти простого копирования я донастроил за несколько минут. А с виндой я воевал несколько месяцев, пока заставил ее работать нормально.

Comment: Windows сам шикарно затирает grub...

Comment: Я уже несколько раз менял таблицу разделов, форматировал диск и делал все возможное, чтобы стереть grub. В итоге я уверен, что grub'a на компьютере нет, проблема в Windows, bios или железе. Только как ее диагностировать я пока не понимаю.

Comment: просто форматирования недостаточно для удаления груба. Нужно ещё "пофискить mbr".

Comment: Последний раз отформатировал в dos, это плохо?

Comment: а кто его знает. Форматирование в dos звучит страшно.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не знаток терминологии, в общем сейчас файловая система - msdos (ну, по gparted'у)

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас несколько винтчестеров, отключите все, кроме того, на котором будет стоять ОС. И с ним работайте.

Мне всегда помогает Acronis Disk Director - форматирование с перезаписью нулями (уничтожит всё и навсегда). Также хороша Victoria.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [Paragon](http://www.paragon.ru/) для полного форматирования HDD (для стирания загрузчика GRUB и установки таблицы разделов). после этого устанавливайте Windows 10 с "чистого" дистрибутива и производите настройку.

Либо вариант поиска конфликтующего драйвера вручную или по номеру ошибки

Comment: Paragon'ом тоже форматировал

Comment: Попробуй тогда скачать нормальную версию windows 10